# How to make a Branch sync with Master Branch automatically in Gitlab

Tags: git, continuous-integration, gitlab, git-merge

I have Branch Develop and Branch Master.
How can I Make the Develop Branch sync with Master, that means if any commit happens to master it should also happens to Develop or the master can also merge to Develop.

We can do it with commands but how can we automate this task

```
git checkout master
git pull
git checkout Develop
git merge master
```

can we come up with the Jenkins job for the same or Gitlab provides any solution?

Any help would be appreciated.

Comment: This makes zero sense to me. You're essentially wanting to double the size of repo unnecessarily via the commit history. It's not like the develop branch is a staging environment that's always up. Devs branch only when they need to work on something independent of the main state of the codebase (ideally stable). If you want to automate the action of syncing *any* branch to master that's a dev-ops thing not solely a git thing, and to that end i'd suggest looking into bash / aliases.

Comment: Jenkins can work and so can Gitlab webhooks. Fewer commands are needed: `git checkout Develop;git pull origin master` and conflicts should be considered.

Comment: Also just another thought, if the repo really is that active, shouldn't you have your develop branch set as the default? i.e. the one that is checked out by default, branched off, etc. Then you'd only merge "develop" into master when it's confirmed stable, right?